# Отправка POST параметров в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, post

Уже третий день бьюсь над тем, как отправить POST параметры на php файл.
Есть три примера кода.
Пример 1:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(adress);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes("lat="+ latitude);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
}
```

Пример 2:

```
String postDataStr(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}

HashMap<String,String> contact=new HashMap<>();
contact.put("lat",latitude);
contact.put("lon",longitude);

try {
    URL url=new URL(adress);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(postDataStr(contact));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    conn.disconnect();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        return "success";
    else
        return "";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Пример 3:

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", latitude));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", longitude));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", id1));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", id2));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key3", id3));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key4", id4));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key5", id5));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key6", id6));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key7", id7));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key8", id8));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key9", id10));

try {
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Ни один из этих примеров не работает. 
Как видно по примеру 3, требуется передать 11 параметров на php, далее он их парсит в таблицу на сервере. Если вбивать параметры напрямую через браузер, то данные заносятся в таблицу, так что выходит, что проблема в приложении.